# A linear regression exercise based on the relationship between $2017$ and $2019$ Math SAT scores

Tags: regression, self-study, estimation, predictive-models, interpretation

We examined the relationship between the 2017 Math SAT scores and the 2019 Math
SAT scores. A StatCrunch simple linear regression printout for the data is shown.

a. Find the least squares prediction equation.

b. Give a practical interpretation of the y-intercept of the least squares line. If a practical
interpretation is not possible, explain why.

c. Give a practical interpretation of the slope of the least squares line. Over what range of
x is the interpretation meaningful?

[image]

Comment: This is certainly a homework assignment. Could you show your works or at least how you tried to approach?

Answer (score 1):

Going purely off the summary here without knowing the data it is derived from, we can probably answer the questions here as following. Keep in mind that I am generalizing here so you can answer the question yourself, as this seems like a copy and pasted homework question:

a) The least squares equation here would be the linear equation you were likely taught in class. It takes on the form $\rm Outcome = Intercept + Slope*Term$. These values are listed in your summary here.

b) The intercept for a Gaussian regression like yours usually represents some conditional mean of the outcome variable (here 2019). Your slope term is a sort of conditional value that says "given this value multiplied by a certain amount, the mean should be this...". However, if the scales of your IV/DV are different, this can alter how you interpret both the slope and intercept.

c) Keep in mind that the slope here is supposed to represent what your outcome value will look like for each one point increase. Consider for a second why that may be an issue on a test that has, say, 100 points. This should give you some kind of answer.

Good luck!

Comment: Shawn, appreciate your post. But it seems OP just posted a question from a possible assignment without showing any work of their own. So, solving totally for them the problem would be against the spirit of the community. So could you trim your post without losing the generality of your answer?

Comment: I understand. I've amended my answer to be more broad in scope.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Shawn.